# gnome-open Works, but also produces error messages [GTK_IS_WIDGET(widget) fails & EOG-WARNING]

Tags: gnome, pdf, evince, widgets, eog

I am currently using gnome-open to open all files for which I do not know the default program (or can't remember it at the time).

With file extension `.pdf`, gnome-open opens the file in my PDF document reader correctly, and then produces this message:

```
(evince:12416): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'G TK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(evince:12416): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

It's not a typo, it outputs the message twice. I do not know what a `widget` is, but clearly this particular widget fails to check out as one.

With file extensions `.jpg`, gnome-open opens the picture with the picture viewer, and then outputs this message:

```
(eog:12448): EOG-WARNING **: Failed to open file '/home/rhobot/.cache/thumbnails/normal/07915f2a54cfeb4b5f53aaa9c4988436.png': No such file or directory
```

I have a few questions:

1) Why does gnome-open work perfectly fine, yet simultaneously produce errors?

2) Why when opening a `.jpg` file, which exists in `/home/rhobot/Pictures` does gnome-open attempt to open a `.png` file that exists in a hidden directory?

3) Most importantly - what do these error messages mean, and how can I fix my system so these errors do not occur?

Even though my files open, and the programs that they open with work just fine, I do not like the idea of my system not running as perfectly as it can. Please help me to diagnose and fix these problems. I am new to Ubuntu, please assume that I know nothing if answering.

Comment: For the error part this question may help you : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230238/starting-x-applications-from-the-terminal-and-the-warnings-that-follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did as a poor workaround is that I created, in my `.bashrc` aliases for each command using GTK+ I start from the shell. For instance the following line for evince

```
alias evince="evince 2>/dev/null"
```